htaccess redirect sometimes the urls a lot of double url
I have sometimes a problem that the browser redirect the url a lot of double urls.
When I enter example.com then the browser redirect to https://www.example.com
Pass
One problem is that google find this with index.php then double content, why?
https://www.example.com - double content with - https://www.example.com/index.php
The next problem is that sometimes the url index.php redirect moretimes.
htts://www.example.com/index.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.phpindex.php...
Why this?
.htaccess
# -FrontPage-

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/index.php

RewriteEngine on
# Two lines to redirect from the root web directory to myfile.php. - Do not work with google index bot
# RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


That setup you describe has nothing that explains the doubling of the "index.php" string in the URL. So there has to be some other factor, most likely some other rewriting rule that you did not tell us about here.

Thanks, I will check the index.php code. And why declared google the root domain and index.php then double content?

Google will index every page that delivers content. You should instead take care to redirect on of those URLs into the other. Or at least declare the same "canonical URL" in both sites.

Specifying an absolute URL for ErrorDocument 404 is also rather wrong. Instead of a 404 response for the originally requested URL, clients will see a redirect status code.

Is it better that I remove this .htaccess ? I see an 404 and an RewriteRule.
I change the 404 to a own 404.php site.
Important is for me, that ever url redirect direct to ** https and www

Thanks. I understand and generade a own 404.php site, that is possible to click on the root url. Is better I think.
Does this lines a problem for redirect?
The goal is that it automatic redirect to the https and www url.
